# Ember computed properties in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I want to implement the following Javascript code in Coffeescript

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNameBindings: ['itemId'],
    itemId: function() {
        console.log(this.get('content'));
        return "item-%@".fmt(this.get('content.id'));
    }.property('content.id'),
    templateName: 'item'    
});
```

Here is what I have so far in coffeescript:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend(
    classNameBindings: ['itemId']

    itemId: ->
        console.log this.get('content')
        contentId = this.get('content.id')
        "item-#{contentId}");
    .property('content.id')

    templateName: 'item'    
)
```

I get:

```
Error: Parse error on line 11: Unexpected '.'
```

The issue seems to be with the dot in `.property('content.id')`
. I dont know how this translates into Coffeescript. How can I properly implement this view in Coffeescript?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's beeing a quite long time, but I think this should be written like this:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend(
  classNameBindings: ['itemId']

  itemId: (->
    console.log this.get('content')
    contentId = this.get('content.id')
    "item-#{contentId}");
  ).property('content.id')

  templateName: 'item'    
)
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! That issue is resolved so I accepted your answer, but I dont think my code is correct, I am trying to figure out how to properly access `content.id` because right now it is undifined. Anyway, the main issue here with converting to coffeescript is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
itemId: (->
  content = @get 'content'
  if content
    return 'item-%@'.fmt(content.get 'id')
  null
).property('content.id')
```

You have to protect computed properties from values that might not be defined yet. That is, your code is fine if there's already an id property on the content object. If content is undefined, then you're not going to be able to look up its ID property and you'll probably see a complaint.

You can also use

```
itemId: Ember.computed(->
  ..
).property('content.id')
```

and a similar pattern for observers. In fact, an observer would also accomplish the same thing without the conditional:

```
itemId: null

contentIdChanged: (->
  @set 'itemId', 'item-%@'.fmt(@get 'content.id')
).observes('content.id')
```

Comment: can you do `'item-%@'.fmt` in coffeescript? I remember getting an error for that

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Ember.computed`.

```
itemId: Ember.computed 'firstName', 'lastName', ->
  "#{@get('firstName')} #{@get('lastName')}"
```

Comment: This looks much better in coffee than those weird parens.