# Coffeescript: Invoking call on function declaration

Tags: coffeescript

Computed properties on ember views have the form

```
myComputedProperty: function() {
    return doSomething();
}.property()
```

However, when I write this in coffescript as

```
myComputedProperty: ->
    doSomething()
.property()
```

I get an error like "Parse error on line 5: Unexpected '.'".  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a quirk of the interpreter I'm using (Mindscape VS plugin)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember computed properties in Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777782/ember-computed-properties-in-coffeescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar of the language doesn't support this. You have to add parenthesis around the function:

```
myComputedProperty: (->
    doSomething()
).property()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `()` around the function, or you can make the syntax more coffeescript friendly:

```
prop = (fn) -> fn.property()

myComputedProperty: prop ->
    doSomething()
```