# Coffeescript Syntax Error

Tags: coffeescript

What's wrong here?

> ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Parse error on line 11: Unexpected '.'

.coffee

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend(
  firstName: null
  lastName: null
  fullName: ->
    firstName = @get("firstName")
    lastName = @get("lastName")
    firstName + " " + lastName
  .property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

Original .js

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  // these will be supplied by `create`
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    var firstName = this.get('firstName');
    var lastName = this.get('lastName');

   return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember computed properties in Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777782/ember-computed-properties-in-coffeescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add braces when you call the method.

```
Person = Ember.Object.extend(
  firstName: null
  lastName: null
  fullName: (->
    firstName = @get("firstName")
    lastName = @get("lastName")
    firstName + " " + lastName
  ).property("firstName", "lastName")
)
```

It is true that they are optional in Coffeescript, but in this situation I think you need to explicitly add them. At least it was the only way I could get it to compile. Perhaps a Coffeescript expert can enlighten as to why.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I made an error in my original answer. The braces should be around the function definition. (edited)