# Coffescript and Ember.js computed properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I need some help converting some javascript into coffeescript to be used with ember. Specifically it is to do with computed properties. I have the following javascript code:

```
Portal.AppsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    sortAscending: true,

    appsCount: function() {
        return this.get('model.length');
    }.property('@each'),

    updated: function() {
        return this.get('model.modified');
    }.property('modified')
});
```

What I am tempted to do is simply:

```
removed for brevity
...
appsCount: ->
    @get 'model.length'
.property '@each'
...
```

but this is not valid syntax. Is this actually possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember computed properties in Coffeescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777782/ember-computed-properties-in-coffeescript) (straight out of the *Related* list in the sidebar...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For computed properties you need to wrap it

```
appsCount: (->
  @get 'model.length'
).property '@each'
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ikatIwaB/1/edit

```
daLength:  (->
  @get 'length'
).property 'length'
```

BTW, I know a few people that are using Ember Script to solve most of the issues you are probably seeing http://emberscript.com/

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this previously but all that gets output when I try to access the property is: [object Object]. I have no idea why this is. Thanks for the link to emberscript, i'll give that a go

Comment: Really?  I wonder if your converter is breaking it, because the jsbin converter likes it (per the example above).